# How to test dart class static constant?

Tags: testing, dart, code-coverage

[image]

Here is my test code:

```
 test('should set correct constant', (){
    expect(Stores.CurrentContext, 'currentContext');
  });
```

but the picture  above shows that the static constant code not tested. and why?

version infos:

```
Flutter 1.2.2-pre.3 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 67cf21577f (4 days ago) • 2019-02-14 23:17:16 -0800
Engine • revision 3757390fa4
Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)
```

Comment: All test passed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A coverage tool registers which code instructions was accessed by the running code.

Think of it as a recording of the memory addresses of "code sections" visited by the Program Counter register
 of the processor stepping through program functions.

A static variable is reached through a data memory access, there are no code instructions involved: 
a variable should be on the stack, on the heap or in a data section if it is a constant.

Consider this code:

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class Stores {
  static const String Login = 'login';
  static const String CurrentContext = 'currentContext';
}

class Store {
  final name;

  static var eMap = Map();

  Store._internal(this.name);     // DA:13

  factory Store(String name) {    // DA:15
    if (eMap.containsKey(name)) { // DA:16
      return eMap[name];          // DA:17
    } else {
      final store = Store._internal(name);  // DA:19
      eMap[name] = store;                   // DA:20
      return store;
    }

  }

}
```

and this code run:

```
test('should set correct constant', (){
  Store('currentContext');
  Store('currentContext');
  expect(Stores.CurrentContext, 'currentContext');
});
```

If you look at the raw output of icov you will notice that lines number of static variable is never reached, giving meaning to the model described above:

```
SF:lib/stores.dart
DA:13,1
DA:15,1
DA:16,2
DA:17,2
DA:19,1
DA:20,2
LF:6
LH:6
```

The visual reporting tool shows a 100% coverage:

[image: LCOV coverage report]

If your reporting tool shows red lines over static variables it has to be considered a "false positive": survive with it or change the reporting tool.

Comment: i know how to reach if / else block,but i don't know how to reach static constant.

Comment: I've tried a simple case with static const and to me icov give 100% coverage, I've flutter 1.1.9.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question, I hope now it is more helpful.

Comment: which reporting tool  you used, mine is  locv-summary and genHtml

Comment: Form ubuntu standard packages: `sudo apt install lcov`

Comment: thanks for your patience !  i will accept your answer

Comment: Hi @attdona, Thanks for this answer. I want to know why this tool is showing functions count 0;